# How to get the trace of process?

Tags: unix, process

Suppose there is a process which is in inactive state from many days and i want to know until what time the process is in active state. Other than the log records where i can get that information?
This is unix platform.

Comment: On what platform? If Windows check Process Explorer

Answer (score 0):

Use [strace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace) debugging utility. You can attach to already running process, save output to log file and analyse it later.

```
[root@localhost ~]#
[root@localhost ~]# strace -o log -p 7166
Process 7166 attached - interrupt to quit
```

Comment: the process has stopped already, we need to identify when it stopped without using any logs